# Building the template for a half-elf nymph in PCGen

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-templates, pcgen

A friend of mine wants to build a half-elf half-nymph using a homebrewed LA 3 half-nymph template, so I need to produce a half-nymph template for LA 3 in PCGen for that character. This means I need to build a template with DR, stunning, blinding, *and* fey and elf traits. How can I do that?

The PCGen documentation doesn't offer much help that I've found, and reverse-engineering the pre-existing templates left me with a broken template, so I need help building a working template.

I need help building the template I *already have on paper in* *templates.lst*. I can't get that to work and believe I'm simply missing something.

**What must be included in a racial template in the templates.lst file in order to see it included in the lists and functional?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about TRPG mechanics, but about the software used.

Comment: I'm voting to leave it open because this site isn't about TRPG mechanics.

Comment: By precedent this is entirely on topic. We have an established track record of supporting people using game-adjacent software. The [tag:pcgen] tag has 16 questions including this one, all of them open.

Comment: The half-nymph template is LA +2, not +7. The nymph creature *is* LA +7, but half-elf is a race, not a template, so you cannot combine half-elf and nymph. So either someone has made a mistake, or you are talking about some houseruled situation that you should explain more in your question.

Comment: To clarify... Again... Im needing assistance understanding the pcgen templates and how to build them in general. Not a critique of my wording. But since that is what recieved focus, i built a half nymph template that gives an LA3 and added that to the half elf... Therefore, half-elf nymph. Now, i need help understanding how to add that template to templates.lst.

Comment: Just my 5 cents: template itself shouldn't probably provide elf traits, it is race what will do it.

Comment: @annoying imp, good point and im not adding the elf traits to the template. Just mentioned it as an example of why i dont want to build it as a race every time i make any given half nymph. Even though its feels like the simpler solution. As an update, i rebuilt the template in the .lst file and still bot appearing in the lists. Would provide a copy but im not sure how or if that would be allowed here anyway.

Comment: @wolf: If the work (`.lst` file) is your own, you can provide it without any license issue. If it's a bit big, say over 50/100 lines, then it may be better to host it on another site and provide a link to the template in your question. For example, copy/paste the content into a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/).

Comment: @matthieu m: ty for the heads up, its my work, but the .lst is stock. Its a single, long line so i should probably save it to .txt so it can remain in context. Ill do that in a bit, trying something new first.